# ReferenceError: coroutine is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a coroutine using `nodejs` version `7.2.1`. 
When I'm writing this code

```
var runfn = coroutine(function * () {

  //... Multiple lines of code

});
```

It generates following error

```
ReferenceError: coroutine is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

I've seen this code in multiple places in google, so I know this code must be correct. Here is 1 link https://x.st/javascript-coroutines/#demo . I didn't found any additional library being used or mentioned here

I wasn't able to find any answer to this in google or with existing stackoverflow question. One thread I found which states that some `co` library needs to be used.

Can anyone point me to the correct one?

Comment: There is no built-in `coroutine` function. Are you using any framework? Have you defined it yourself?

Comment: Here is 1 link https://x.st/javascript-coroutines/#demo . I didn't found any additional library being used or mentioned here

Comment: [RTFM](https://x.st/javascript-coroutines/#the-convenient-coroutine-wrapper)

Comment: Thanks James.. not sure why and how I have missed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the linked article, scroll down to `The Convenient coroutine Wrapper`. They provided their own definition...